# Dropdown Menu not clickable

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm stuck with a dropdown menu i made. 
When I hover a menu item, a dropdown appears, but i can't seem to click the dropdown items because there is a blank space between the dropdown and the menu.

this is my code:

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;

}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


nav ul {

float : right;
padding: 0px 10px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #fff;

    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #000;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 0px 10px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #fff; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 

         position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 0px 20px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #fff;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

does anyone has an idea?

you can see the code in : http://dropdown.kiran.be

ty

K

Comment: Can you post your code on CodePen or JSFiddle?  CSS, HTML and JS

Answer (score 0):

just add 
   left:0

to your nav ul ul (drop down menu)
and remove the margin-bottom from nav ul li (it inherits some margin from your base.css you can see whats going on if you use firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you make the UL appear when you hover a li:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>sub one</li>
      <li>sub two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;}

ul li:hover ul.sub {
  display:block;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the ul margin that you have now. So this is a possible solution:

```
ul li ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

You should even remove the margin on top of the drop-down menu. I can't click on it because it slips away!